# Python/unitest: Is it possible to have the same function called many times and test not interrupted in case of failure?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm testing a module with Python `unittest` library. I'd like to call a unt test methos with different arguments, but would like each call to be a separate test case:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_all(self):
        for x in range(10):
            self.do_test_one(x)
              
    def do_test_one(self,x):
        print( "Testing " + str(x) )
        self.assertTrue( x != 5 )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    unittest.main()
```

This reports:

```
Testing 0
Testing 1
Testing 2
Testing 3
Testing 4
Testing 5
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_all (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 8, in test_all
    self.do_test_one(x)
  File "so.py", line 12, in do_test_one
    self.assertTrue( x != 5 )
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I'd like to get, having each function be a separate test:

```
Testing 0
Testing 1
Testing 2
Testing 3
Testing 4
Testing 5
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_all (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 8, in test_all
    self.do_test_one(x)
  File "so.py", line 12, in do_test_one
    self.assertTrue( x != 5 )
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing 6
Testing 7
Testing 8
Testing 9

Ran 10 test in 0.014s

FAILED (passed=9, failures=1)
```

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: It must be a duplicate, but I can't find one quickly. Use [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest) context manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest):

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_all(self):
        for x in range(10):
            self.do_test_one(x)

    def do_test_one(self, x):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
            print(f'Testing {x}')
            self.assertTrue(x != 5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
Testing 0
Testing 1
Testing 2
Testing 3
Testing 4
Testing 5
FTesting 6
Testing 7
Testing 8
Testing 9

======================================================================
FAIL: test_all (__main__.TestStringMethods.test_all) (x=5)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in do_test_one
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `test_all()` function will abort on the first failure. To do what you want, you need parameterized tests. Unfortunately `unittest` doesn't support this. I recommend that you check out `pytest` instead. It allows you to do something similar.

Instead of an explicit loop to run the test, you create a test that takes a parameter. Then you define list of all the combinations of values you want to use for that parameter. This allows the runner to run independent tests for each of the values.